# reduce wide table

Tags: tables

How can I reduce the space between the columns in my table?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[para,online,flushleft]{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{lccccccccccc}
\toprule
Sample& Source &$\alpha$&$\beta$&$\gamma$&$\delta$ &$\eta$&$ \theta$&$\kappa$&$ \xi $&$ o $&$ \pi $\\
\midrule
$\mu$ &45&648.1&62&9312&45282&2560&29&450&045555&21545&54620318\\
\midrule
$ \nu$&68545
&633.1&51.7&80.5&452.7&251.0&290.7&-199.3&0.231&25600012&6521202\\
\midrule
$ \upsilon $&4455 &607&53.7&84.4&426.3&239.8&278.8&-186.1&0.238&21221&54821\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can try to put distance  manualy using some examples here https://github.com/AnMnv/eBook

Comment: Try ` \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}` in your preamble (the default is 6pt).

Comment: With \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt} is Ok, thank you

Answer (score 2):

The result is a bit tight, but the columns are separated. With `tabular*` and `\tabcolsep` set to zero we let TeX compute the spaces.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\caption{Some caption}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  c
  *{10}{>{$}c<{$}}
  @{}
}
\toprule
Sample & Source & \alpha & \beta & \gamma & \delta & \eta & \theta & \kappa & \xi & o & \pi \\
\midrule
$\mu$ &45&648.1&62&9312&45282&2560&29&450&045555&21545&54620318\\
\midrule
$\nu$ &68545
&633.1&51.7&80.5&452.7&251.0&290.7&-199.3&0.231&25600012&6521202\\
\midrule
$\upsilon$ &4455 &607&53.7&84.4&426.3&239.8&278.8&-186.1&0.238&21221&54821\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

With `>{$}c<{$}` we obtain a center aligned column with entries in math mode, so the minus signs are correct.

[image]

If your text width is a bit more generous, you could also try `\small` instead of `\footnotesize`. The result with the standard text width is not as good:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to mess with it. I would redesign the table though

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[para,online,flushleft]{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \small
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  % note \enspace is more or less \kern0.5em
\caption{}
\begin{threeparttable}
  \begin{tabular}{
      !{\enspace}
      l
      !{\enspace}
      c
      !{\enspace}
      c
      !{\enspace}
      c
      !{\enspace}
      c
      !{\enspace}
      c
      !{\enspace}
      c
      !{\enspace}
      c
      !{\enspace}
      c
      !{\enspace}
      c
      !{\enspace}
      c
      !{\enspace}
      c
      !{\enspace}
    }
\toprule
Sample       & Source & $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma$ & $\delta$ & $\eta$ & $ \theta$ & $\kappa$ & $ \xi $  & $ o $ & $ \pi $  \\
\midrule
$\mu$        & 45     & 648.1    & 62      & 9312     & 45282    & 2560   & 29        & 450      & 045555   & 21545 & 54620318 \\
% \midrule
$ \nu$       & 68545
             & 633.1  & 51.7     & 80.5    & 452.7    & 251.0    & 290.7  & $-199.3$  & 0.231    & 25600012 & 6521202          \\
% \midrule
$ \upsilon $ & 4455   & 607      & 53.7    & 84.4     & 426.3    & 239.8  & 278.8     & $-186.1$ & 0.238    & 21221 & 54821    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```